# Assign variables in one line in Python

Tags: python, variables

Is it ok to assign variables like this in Python?:

`mean, variance, std = 0`

Comment: Those aren't declarations.  It's an attempt at an assignment.  You want this:  `a = b = c = 0`.  Just replace the commas with `=`.

Comment: Terminology note: python *doesn't have variable declarations* (although, you can kind of think of type annotations as declarations). This is a variable *definition*. In any case, what do you mean by "OK"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Python has two types of variable declarations:  `global` and `nonlocal`.  That doesn't apply here, but it's worth noting.

Comment: @TomKarzes sort of, I wouldn't consider those variable *declarations*, they do not *create a variable*, they are directives that tell the compiler what scope the variable has.

Comment: Or: `mean, variance, std, max, min, sum = (0,)*6`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Declarations don't necessarily create variables.  They declare them.  For example, in C there are external declarations that declare externally defined variables.  In any case, here's a direct quote from the Python documentation:  "The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block."  So they refer to it as a declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options for one-liners:

This version is only safe if assigning immutable object values like int, str, and float.  Don't use this with mutable objects like list and dict objects.

```
mean = variance = std = max = min = sum = 0
```

Another option is a bit more verbose and does not have issues with mutable objects.  You can raise ValueError errors if you don't have the same number of objects on each side.

```
mean, variance, std, max, min, sum = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Or: `mean, variance, std, max, min, sum = (0,)*6`

Comment: Instead of `a, b, c = 0, 0, 0` you could do `a = 0; b = 0; c = 0`.  I don't see a particular advantage to cramming it all on one line though, unless the value really is guaranteed to be the same, in which case `a = b = c = 0` does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?

```
>>> mean, variance, std, max, min, sum = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

It must be:

```
mean = variance = std = max_ = min_ = sum_ = 0
```

Unless you have a deal with `int`, `bool` it is ok.

You can check it easily:

```
>>> id(mean) == id(variance)
True
>>> id(mean) == id(variance)
True
>>> mean = 1
>>> id(mean) == id(variance)
False
```

But:

```
>>> mean = variance = std = max_ = min_ = sum_ = {}
>>> mean['a'] = '1'
>>> variance['a']
'1'
>>> del mean['a']
>>> variance
{}
>>>
```

They all are the same. And please don't use `sum`, `min`, `max` as var names - it is a reserved word in Python.